# Unresolved external symbol S_ISDIR in C upon checking if directory exist

Tags: c, windows, stat, unresolved-external

I searched the web on how to check if path provided is a file or a directory and came across the `stat` system call.

I tried to implement as following :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int isDirectoryExists(const char *path)
{
    struct stat stats;

    stat(path, &stats);

    // Check for file existence
    if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

but when i try to compile with visual studio on windows i get the following error:

```
unresolved external symbol S_ISDIR referenced in function
```

I read the documentation of stat and it does provide this macro but for some reason my environment is recognizing it...any suggestions?

Alternative solution would be implementing what S_ISDIR is doing:

```
stat(pathname, &sb);
if ((sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR) {
      /* Handle directory */
}
```

Comment: *I read the documentation of stat*. Assuming it is [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). Do you include the required headers? With 777 rep I assume you know that you should include a complete minimum sample including all the headers, compiler command, etc...

Comment: BTW: Don't you get a warning about implicite declaration of `S_ISDIR`? I would assume that symbol should not make it to the linker at all.

Comment: It means that the `<sys/stat.h>` header is not POSIX compliant (assuming it is included).   You may have to provide the macro.  `#ifndef S_ISDIR` / `#define S_ISDIR(s) ((s).st_mode & S_IFDIR)` / `#endif`.  Rinse and repeat for other similar macros.

Comment: BTW: your code is wrong anyway because you don't check if `stat` succeeds. If `stat` failes for whatever reason, it's pointless to check `stats.st_mode` because it's content will be undetermined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What?  Windows is not compliant with the **Portable** Operating System Interface standards?!?!!  Say it isn't so!

Comment: The outline macro in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71674639/unresolved-external-symbol-s-isdir-in-c-upon-checking-if-directory-exist/71677798#comment126671512_71674639) is wrong in detail though correct in principle.  My excuse is that I was typing on an iPhone in the app in the middle of the night while not sleeping particularly well.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into problems with Microsoft not providing a POSIX-compliant version of `<sys/stat.h>`.  I have my own header, `sysstat.h`, that deals with the problem (earliest date 1995, last modified 2013):

```c
#ifndef SYSSTAT_H
#define SYSSTAT_H

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif /* HAVE_CONFIG_H */

#include "posixver.h"           /* Not always quick enough */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER                 /* MS <sys/stat.h> uses this trigger */
typedef unsigned short mode_t;  /* POSIX defines mode_t in <sys/types.h> */
#endif /* _MSCVER */

#ifndef S_IRWXU

/* POSIX-compliant defines omitted from sys/stat.h. */
/* Assume UNIX Version 7 header, more or less       */

#ifndef S_IREAD
#define S_IREAD     0400
#endif /* S_IREAD */
#ifndef S_IWRITE
#define S_IWRITE    0200
#endif /* S_IWRITE */
#ifndef S_IEXEC
#define S_IEXEC     0100
#endif /* S_IEXEC */

#define S_IRUSR (S_IREAD)
#define S_IWUSR (S_IWRITE)
#define S_IXUSR (S_IEXEC)
#define S_IRGRP (S_IRUSR >> 3)
#define S_IWGRP (S_IWUSR >> 3)
#define S_IXGRP (S_IXUSR >> 3)
#define S_IROTH (S_IRUSR >> 6)
#define S_IWOTH (S_IWUSR >> 6)
#define S_IXOTH (S_IXUSR >> 6)
#define S_IRWXU (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR)
#define S_IRWXG (S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IXGRP)
#define S_IRWXO (S_IROTH|S_IWOTH|S_IXOTH)

#ifdef _MSC_VER                 /* MS <sys/stat.h> uses this trigger */
/* MS Windows does not support SUID, SGID or sticky bit */
#ifndef S_ISUID
#define S_ISUID 0
#endif
#ifndef S_ISGID
#define S_ISGID 0
#endif
#ifndef S_ISVTX
#define S_ISVTX 0
#endif
#else
#ifndef S_ISUID
#define S_ISUID 04000
#endif
#ifndef S_ISGID
#define S_ISGID 02000
#endif
#ifndef S_ISVTX
#define S_ISVTX 01000
#endif
#endif /* _MSCVER */

#endif /* S_IRWXU */

/*
** Assume the S_IFMT, S_IFDIR, S_IFCHR, S_IFREG are defined, which is OK
** for Windows under MS Visual Studio 2008 Express.  Conditional testing
** not perfect: it assumes pragmatically that S_ISFIFO() is undefined if
** S_IFIFO() is undefined, for example.
*/

/* POSIX file type test macros */
#ifndef S_ISDIR
#define S_ISDIR(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
#endif /* S_ISDIR */
#ifndef S_ISCHR
#define S_ISCHR(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFCHR)
#endif /* S_ISCHR */
#ifndef S_ISREG
#define S_ISREG(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
#endif /* S_ISREG */

/* Not in MS Visual Studio 2008 Express */
#ifdef S_IFBLK
#ifndef S_ISBLK
#define S_ISBLK(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFBLK)
#endif /* S_ISBLK */
#else
#define S_ISBLK(m)  (0)
#endif /* S_IFBLK */

/* Not in Version 7 Unix, but we'll define it anyway */
#ifdef S_IFIFO
#ifndef S_ISFIFO
#define S_ISFIFO(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFIFO)
#endif /* S_ISFIFO */
#else
#define S_ISFIFO(m) (0)
#endif /* S_IFIFO */

/* Not in POSIX 1003.1-1990, but we'll define it anyway */
#ifdef S_IFLNK
#ifndef S_ISLNK
#define S_ISLNK(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)
#endif /* S_ISLNK */
#else
#define S_ISLNK(m)  (0)
#endif /* S_IFLNK */

/* Not in POSIX 1003.1-1990, but we'll define it anyway */
#ifdef S_IFSOCK
#ifndef S_ISSOCK
#define S_ISSOCK(m) (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFSOCK)
#endif /* S_ISSOCK */
#else
#define S_ISSOCK(m) (0)
#endif /* S_IFSOCK */

#endif  /* SYSSTAT_H */
```

The `posixver.h` header contains:

```c
#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2008 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700   /* SUS v4, POSIX 1003.1 2008/13 (POSIX 2008/13) */
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700   /* SUS v4, POSIX 1003.1 2008/13 (POSIX 2008/13) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

Just to be explicit: you may use this code however you like, and I do not require attribution.